# Kirchhoff law in Electronics Workbench

Tags: basic, kirchhoffs-laws

I have a task to check Kirchhoff laws in this circuit.[image]

If I understand everything right, I3 + I2 should be equal to I1, but it isn't. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9.649mA + 32.16mA = 41.81mA Your I3 meter needs to be flipped around, and you'll get the result you expect. Take this as a lesson in understanding both the simulator and circuit. If you don't understand both, interpreting the results is an exercise in futility.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't even thought that there's such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Kirchoff's Current Law is most correctly stated as "The sum of all currents into and out of a node is equal to 0". As shown in the diagram, I1 and I3 flow into the node, and I2 flows out. Therefore the correct equation is "I1 + I3 = I2".

Comment: Hmm, I thought that there are two circuits - first includes R1 and R3 and second - R1 and R2. How does it happen that I3 and I1 flow into the node?

Comment: @AndrewVershinin: Because that's what you've decided with the orientation of your meters.